# Ряды в C++, помогите с задачкой, пожалуйста

Tags: c++, ряды

Не могу понять, как можно реализовать это (если можно, попробуйте объяснить мне, как все нужно делать):

При значениях x и Е, определяемых вводом, вычислить сумму тех слагаемых
заданного вида, которые по абсолютной величине больше Е. Подсчитать количество таких
слагаемых N. Выполнить суммирование для двух значений Е, отличающихся на порядок
(в 10 раз)

|x| < 1
arcctg (x) = PI/2 - x + x^3/3 - x^5/5 + ... + (-1)^n * x^(2n - 1)/(2n - 1)

Comment: Например, просто вычисляя каждый член и суммируя их в цикле, пока разность модулей двух соседних членов не станет меньше E. Можно каждый последующий член получать из предыдущего (что немного умнее). Попробуйте, набросайте какой-то код, а то пока ваш вопрос подозрительно смахивает на "сделайте за меня домашку". На сайте ну очень много вопросов на ту тему - почему вы не [выполнили поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d1%8b) сначала?

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. В том-то и дело, что я пока не особо шарю в высшей математике, первую половину программы с суммой я сделал, а вот с этой фигней пока не смог разобраться, только сейчас буду писать код, когда вникну

Comment: Как только вы что-то сделаете самостоятельно, так сразу возникнут основания помогать :) И еще - все же познакомьтесь с сайтом, а то вы ведь даже не прочли первую страницу... А когда отвечаете человеку - ставьте @ с его именем рядом (типа, @Harry) - тогда ему приходит уведомление; иначе можно и пропустить ответ.

Comment: @Harry спасибо за информацию, я все понял)

Comment: @Harry, я вот так сделал по итогу, можете проконсультировать, все ли верно

double y = 1;
    for (; fabs(last) > e;) {

     last = pow(-1, y) * pow(x, 2 * y - 1) / (2 * y - 1);

     summa += last;

     y++;
    }

Comment: Отвечать много, ответил ответом :)

Answer (score 1):

Ну, а немного "причесал" ваш код...

```
double Paul(double x, double eps)
{
    double y = 1, summa = 0, last = 1;;
    for (; fabs(last) > eps;)
    {
        last = pow(-1, y) * pow(x, 2 * y - 1) / (2 * y - 1);
        summa += last;
        y+=1;
    }
    return pi/2 + summa;
}

double Harry(double x, double eps)
{
    double summ = pi/2 - x, x2n_1 = -x;
    x *= x;

    for(int k = 3; fabs(x2n_1/k) > eps; k += 2)
    {
        x2n_1 *= -x;
        summ += x2n_1/k;
    }
    return summ;
}
```

Получается, что он считает [так же, как и мой](https://ideone.com/7aZCr9), а главное - как и арккотангенс :)

Так что все нормально. Только мой просто потому, что не вычисляет все эти `pow`, считает примерно [в восемь раз быстрее](https://ideone.com/NuGWhW), так что посмотрите просто из интереса, чем он отличается от вашего..